# Building knowledge graphs with Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, semantic-web

I am trying to extract a knowledge graph from Wikipedia articles.
To extract the necessary triples I am using Stanford CoreNLP. Unfortunately the quality of the mined triples does not hold up to what I expected.

Example:

"Johann Carl Friedrich Gauss was a German mathematician and physicist who made significant contributions to many fields in mathematics and sciences. Sometimes referred to as the Princeps mathematicorum, Gauss had an exceptional influence in many fields of mathematics and science."

`(physicist,make contribution to, many field)`

What techniques may improve my result? Are there better tools to mine triples from text?

Comment: Such knowledge graphs already exist, e.g see this entry from the Wikidata https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6722  which can be combined with many other entities from WIkidata e.g. by using SPARQL

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution, written in Java:

https://github.com/sunil3590/artificial-guy

Stanford's CoreNLP is used.  According to the project's [`main` method](https://github.com/sunil3590/artificial-guy/blob/a82228c16a73b394d5a42871386cef855e43514d/src/main/java/edu/ncsu/artificialGuy/ArtificialGuy.java#L16-L21), the author has implemented:

- Co-reference resolution
- Part-of-speech tagging
- NER tagging
- Stemming
- Dependency parse